# serializer set custom values

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model serializer that is like so -

```
class VariableSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner_name = serializers.Field(source='owner_id.owner_name')

    class Meta:
        model = Varmst
        resource_name = 'varmst'
        fields = ('varmst_id', 'varmst_type', 'varmst_name', 'varmst_value',
            'varmst_desc')
```

'varmst_value' corresponds to an integer that, depending on that integer can mean a different thing.  How do I return the normalized value OVER the integer?

ie.
if 'varmst_value' = 2 then I want the serializer to return 'varmst_type': 'email'
if 'varmst_value' = 3 then I want the serializer to return 'varmst_type': 'website'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the following solution can help you

```
class VariableSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner_name = serializers.Field(source='owner_id.owner_name')

    class Meta:
        model = Varmst
        resource_name = 'varmst'
        fields = ('varmst_id', 'varmst_type', 'varmst_name', 'varmst_value',
                  'varmst_desc')

    def transform_varmst_type(self, obj, value):
        if obj.varmst_value == 2:
            return "email"
        if obj.varmst_value == 3:
            return "Website"
```

Comment: It's returning a null value instead of the number now so it looks like it's working in part.  Just not sure why it's not changing the value?

Comment: If I change the return to simply "pass" it's still leaving as null so something in finding the object is rendering it null?

Comment: my bad.  corrected I explained it wrong your code works.  I had to have if obj.varmst_type ==2: return "email".